# Give an example to illustrate that $\lim_{x\to 0}\ f(x)$ is not always equal to $\lim_{x\to 0}\ f(2x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

It's really hard to come up with such an example. My professor said that the example won't be made up of ILATE functions. It would be something like signum, gif etc.

Comment: How could they even be different?

Comment: thats what you gotta figure out!

Comment: @adityagupta, if you take the limit at $0$, they will be same.

Comment: Either your professor tricked you, or there is something you don't tell us.

Comment: Should $f$ be defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$? If not, then I can solve it, I think.

Comment: This is nonsense as stated. Possibly what he asked for is not exactly what you say?

Comment: I agree that it is nonsense as stated. Probably something is missing.

Comment: However I think that I can find $f$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is not defined but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x)$ is defined.

Comment: And was not it a multivariable function?

Comment: There is *no* function $f$ where $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x)$ both are defined but different. There are however functions (not defined on all of $\mathbb R$) where the former limit does not exist while the latter does. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2855636/168433 for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Although, I don't know where you get this proposition, my implication shows

> If $f$ is a real-valued function on $\Bbb{R}$, such that $\lim_{x\to
>  0} f(x)$ exists then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(2x)$ exists and equal to
>   $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$.

I am going to prove this statement.
Let, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L\in\Bbb{R}$ and define $g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(2x)\quad\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$
To prove $\lim_{x\to 0} f(2x)=L$, it is enough to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=L$
Choose $\varepsilon >0$
Then $\exists \delta_\varepsilon >0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\quad\forall x\in(-\delta_\varepsilon,\delta_\varepsilon)\backslash\{0\} $
$\implies |f(2x)-L|<\varepsilon\quad \forall x\in\left(-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}{2},\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}{2}\right )\backslash\lbrace 0 \rbrace$
$\implies |g(x)-L|<\varepsilon\quad\forall x\in \left (-\delta_\varepsilon',\delta_\varepsilon'\right )\backslash\{0\}$ where $\delta_\varepsilon' =\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}{2} >0$
For any $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists\delta_\varepsilon'>0$ such that $|g(x)-L|<\varepsilon\quad\forall x\in \left (-\delta_\varepsilon',\delta_\varepsilon'\right )\backslash\{0\}$
$\implies \lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=L\implies\lim_{x\to 0} f(2x)=L=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$(Proved)
**This is true only when we are taking limit at $0$ i.e. $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ may not be equal to $\lim_{x\to c} f(2x)$ for any $c\in\Bbb{R}$**(Why?)
You can verify this result geometrically also(Hint: To obtain the graph of $x\mapsto f(2x)$, shrink the graph of $f$ horizontally by $\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $f(\xi) \to L$ as $\xi \to 0$, this means that

$$|f(2x) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{whenever} \quad |2x| < \delta$$

but this just means that $|x| < \delta/2$ implies $|f(2x) - L| < \epsilon$

so $f(2x) \to L$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \{ p/3^n \mid p, n \in \mathbb N \} \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(p/3^n) = (-1)^p.$ Then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is not defined but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x)$ is defined and equals $1.$

Comment: this was kinda the one that i thought, but yours is much more elegant. thanks for the help

Comment: Note that one limit exists and the other does not. You can not find a function where both limits exist and are different.